# Cant access SVN Server even locally

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I have installed VisualSVN Server 2.5.8 and Tortoise SVN 1.7.11.

My repositories are added to the SVN and can be seen in VisualSVN Server Manager.

However, I am not able to access the repository by browsing the URL or by right clicking on the repository and selecting browse menu.

I am using port 8443 and that port is open. Internet Explorer is in loading mode indefinitely when URL is fired on the browser.

What could this be?

Answer (score 2):

If you have TortoiseSVN 1.7, you, probably also have CLI-client in TortoiseSVN installation.

Before you proceed on SU, please

- Copy URL to the root of amy repo in Visual SVN Manager
- In command prompt, run `svn ls URL-OF-REPO` and show output of command in question
- You can also try to use this URL in browser (nicer, but less informative in case of errors)